# Multiple DependsOnTargets do not execute

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild, targets

I have a build task that I am working on using msbuild. 
Within the task I have several targets, some of which perform preparation work.

When I execute *"msbuild myEvent.msbuild /t:event3"* the event runs. The first event in the DependsOnTargets executes but the second event in the list of targets does not. 
Example

```
<!-- only event1 will fire -->
<Target Name="event3" DependsOnTargets="event1; event2">
   <Task TaskAction="myAction3"/>
</Target>
<Target Name="event1" DependsOnTargets="event4">
   ... do tasks here
</Target>
<Target Name="event2" >
   ... do tasks here
</Target>
<Target Name="event4" >
</Target>
```

I have attempted to modify this by eliminating the space in the DependsOnTargets values. I ensure that I have semicolon separated values. I have tried using BeforeTargets and AfterTargets without success.

My msbuild code targets ToolsVersion  4.0.

Is there something that I am missing with how DependsOnTargets works?

**EDIT**

- I think I figured out my problem. MSBuild does not allow me to execute the same target more than once.
- In this case I have to do the following

  - start a database service
  - drop databases
  - stop the service
  - Extract some database files from a zip file
  - start the database service
  - Attach databases
  - Perform further action on databases ...
- The first start database service will execute as well as drop databases and stopping the service. The next call to start the database service fails.

Comment: After thinking through this some more I think I know the problem. The problem is that in my sequence of events, I call one of the events multiple times. Since the event already ran once, the event does not get called again. In my case I have to start a service, perform an action, stop a service, perform another action while service is stopped, and then start the service again to perform another action. :)

Comment: I am trying to utilize a target like a task in order to reduce repeated code. A target will execute once and only once it appears.

Comment: Yes, a target never runs twice during a single build, even if a subsequent target in the build depends on it. Once a target runs, its contribution to the build is complete. Since your original issue has been solved, you can post an answer and mark it after 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because I was treating a target like a task; I was trying to reduce duplicate code.

Once a target executes, it never executes again. So the takeaway here is to be clear what is a target and what is a task.

I currently have this resolved by removing the targets that are intended to be tasks and create the required tasks, such as starting and stopping services, within the correct targets.